# Polling the temperature of a processor

Tags: assembly, hardware

All of the questions I can find related to CPU temperature are done above the OS level and generally involve lm-sensors.

I am looking to figure out where on the actual CPU the temperature sensor is located, and all of my searching is cluttered with userspace code.

My assumption is that there's some analog thermal sensor and it's connected to a (probably relatively primitive) ADC. However I can't seem to verify that assumption. I'm looking to do this for both x86 and ARM (I assume it will also be cpu dependent, I'm not afraid to dig through datasheets).

My main issue here is I don't know what to search for, things like "cpu temperature x86" or "temperature register cortex A9" don't give me anything useful, and I don't know where to look in the 4000+ page TRM for this info.

I'm mostly looking for some guidance to the right location for this information, even just a step down the right path.

Comment: The Linux kernel has drivers for the Intel on-die temperature sensor, and Intel publishes data sheets for it somewhere.  If you look at exactly how lm-sensors gets its data (system calls, or doing I/O itself), that should narrow in on what you need to look up.

Comment: That indeed depends on cpu model. You will need to consult the appropriate documentation such as the _BIOS and Kernel
 Developer's Guide (BKDG) for AMD Family 15h Models 00h-0Fh Processors_ which has _"D18F3xA4 Reported Temperature Control"_

Comment: Thanks @Jester. Do you know what would be the best search terms? "Temperature" is not giving me the best results. I'm looking at some of NXP's processors and their TRM's aren't easy to navigate